# Is evolving with two level 2 cards better than evolving with a level 1?

Tags: prime-world-defenders

Someone has told me that evolving with two cards that have been previously evolved will give you better stats than if one of them has never been evolved *(so, using four cards total to get the final card, rather than the usual three)*.

I can't find anything online to back that up.  Is it true?

Comment: It seems that evolving two evolution 2 stage cards together can give you better stats on the final evolution 3 card. I say that based on the hint contained in these patch notes posted by the developers to Steam. URL: http://steamcommunity.com/app/235360/discussions/0/864974467778341677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you use two evolution level 2 cards to evolve into the final evolution 3 tower card, the resulting evolution 3 tower card will be slightly stronger than a tower card that used an evolution 1 + evolution 2 cards to evolve to an evolution 3 tower. I was able to quickly test this with Fire Towers, comparing a maxed 1 + 2 evolved 3 Fire tower, to a maxed 2 + 2 Evolution 3 Fire Tower. The 2 + 2 Evolution 3 Fire Tower is slightly stronger.

Comment: It is actually a 45% increase which is better than "slightly stronger".